# jQuery add remove classes in select box and buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, addclass, removeclass

I have two select boxes and a few buttons as post category filters. Check out my **[Fiidle](http://jsfiddle.net/cYFLe/10/)**. I want to add a background color when I click any of the buttons or select boxes and remove it when I click another. The effect is exactly the same as 
in this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/vNZ49/1/).

I guess I have to register a `change` event on the select box. However, as a beginner, all I can come up with is mincing this code

```
$selectors.change(function() 
{
     var $selector = $(this);
     var cat = $selector.data('product-collection__category');
     $selectors.removeClass('product-collection__selector--active');
     $selector.addClass('product-collection__selector--active');
});
```

and turning it into this invalid code

```
$selectors.change(function() 
{
     var $selector = $(this);
     var cat = $selector.find('option:selected').data('product-collection__category');
     $selectors.removeClass('filterselect__selector--active');
     $selector.addClass('filterselect__selector--active'); 
});
```

Would anyone please show me how to get this to work?

Comment: you want to apply background to who ? can u explain more ?

Comment: @Saurabh when any of the buttons or select boxes is clicked, I want it to change the background color to green, and then change back to its original color when I click on any other button or option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add below css for effect.

```
.product-collection__selector:hover {
    background: green;
}
.product-collection__selector {
    -webkit-transition:background-color 0.3s ease-in;
    -moz-transition:background-color 0.3s ease-in;
    -o-transition:background-color 0.3s ease-in;
    transition:background-color 0.3s ease-in;
}
```

**JS Change**

replace

```
var $dropdown = $collection.find('.filterselect');

 var $selectors = $collection.find('.product-collection__selector,.filterselect__selector');
```

with

```
var $selectors = $collection.find('.filterselect');
```

Add below code in your change event to remove active `class` from  `li`

```
$collection.find('li').removeClass('product-collection__selector--active');
```

[**Updated DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cYFLe/11/)

**EDIT ANSWER**

Don't need to replace as above just add below two line code. and make changes as below:

```
var $dropdown = $collection.find('.filterselect');
var $selectors = $collection.find('.product-collection__selector,.filterselect__selector');
```

replace

```
$selectors.change(function () 
AND
$selectors.removeClass('filterselect__selector--active');
```

with

```
$dropdown.change(function ()
AND
$dropdown.removeClass('filterselect__selector--active');
```

**[NEW UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cYFLe/19/)**

Comment: It's close. Is it possible to remove the class `product-collection__selector--active` from the button I previously clicked when I select an option in the select box?

Comment: When `.product-collection__selector` being removed from `var $selectors`, the button filters aren't functioning anymore. How would you get them to work alongside with the select boxes? Create a new var for the buttons?

Comment: @user35295 please check my answer i have added some code underneath of edited answer label.

Answer (score 1):

The [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cYFLe/5/) solves the problem of background color. Onchange event works on select node and not on options. Also there was not much requirement applying .each on the container div.

```
var $selectors = $('select.filterselect');
```

You can use jQuery node traversal, .parent, .parents, .children, .find methods to locate the nearest container in which you want to modify the data based on the select box which is changed.

Hope this helps.